# How to establish a many-to-many relationship between entities kept in separate services and separate databases in microservice architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my NormalUser entity :

```
public class NormalUser : BaseUser
{
    public AnonymUser AnonymUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> JoinedSessionIds { get; set; }
}
```

I will have another entity named Session, but it will be defined in a different service and in a different database. There is a many-to-many relationship between Session and NormalUser. I tried to establish this relationship by storing the id's in the form of a list, but it is not possible for me to store it this way in sql server. What would you recommend me?

Comment: Session table should exist in both databases, with only session id available in the provided example. OR these two services should be merged into one if they rely on each other too often

Comment: What if I just add a table called UserSession to each database and set up the relationship that way?

Comment: yeah, it is basically what I suggested

Comment: It sounds like @YehorAndrosov's answer is spot on?  "these two services should be merged into one if they rely on each other too often"

Comment: You can't directly store a list of SessionID in the NormalUser entity because they are in different DB and services.Instead of storing SessionID use unique GUID to reference Session.ServiceA generates GUID for each Session & exposes them thru API.ServiceB stores the GUID associated with each NormalUser.Publish events when NormalUser joins a Session.ServiceA listens to these events and maintains a mapping of NormalUser IDs and SessionIDs.Create serviceC to manage the m-to-m relation.Both ServiceA & ServiceB can interact with ServiceC to get info about the relation between normalUser and Session